# Member function pointer error: Reference to non-static member function must be called

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, cocos2d-x

```
this->scheduleOnce(schedule_selector(SelectGameScene::startGameCallback),this, 0.0f, false);
```

I got an error : Reference to non-static member function must be called.

```
void startGameCallback(float dt); //in h file

void SelectGameScene::startGameCallback(float dt)
{
    Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(TransitionFade::create(TRANSITION_TIME,     GameScene::createScene()));
}
```

Where

```
#define CC_SCHEDULE_SELECTOR(_SELECTOR) static_cast<cocos2d::SEL_SCHEDULE>(&_SELECTOR)
typedef void (Ref::*SEL_SCHEDULE)(float);
```

I got this error on XCode with c++11 standard and cococ2d-x ver4.0 library.

**Update:** I tried this code

```
this->scheduleOnce(schedule_selector(&SelectGameScene::startGameCallback),this, 0.0f, false);
```

I got an error Use of undeclared identifier 'schedule_selector'

**Update2** I found the problem. I created this class through static method createScene.

```
class SelectGameScene : public cocos2d::Layer
{
 public:
   static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCode compiler thinks that SelectGameScene::startGameCallback is static method but it is just a member function pointer. So I decide to rewrite this statement.

from

```
this->scheduleOnce(schedule_selector(SelectGameScene::startGameCallback),0.0f);
```

to

```
auto funPointer = static_cast<cocos2d::SEL_SCHEDULE>(&SelectGameScene::startGameCallback);
this->scheduleOnce(funPointer, 0.0f);
```

because

```
#define CC_SCHEDULE_SELECTOR(_SELECTOR) static_cast<cocos2d::SEL_SCHEDULE>(&_SELECTOR)
```

Answer (score 3):

The sytax `SelectGameScene::startGameCallback` is not valid. It must have the `&`:

```
this->scheduleOnce(schedule_selector(&SelectGameScene::startGameCallback),this, 0.0f, false);
//                                   ^---- there
```

Comment: May be XCode settings wrong or something else because we use SelectGameScene::startGameCallback without &. https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/search?q=schedule_selector&unscoped_q=schedule_selector

Comment: @Voloda2 If you use a macro that adds the `&`, sure. Otherwise, it's non standard and can fail like the code in your question. Usually, compiler won't allow it if you disable extensions.

Comment: I created my object through a static method. This is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be reproduced in v4. It's caused by deprecated macros that was in "CCRef.h" and they are now gone.

Simply replacing "schedule_selector" with "CC_SCHEDULE_SELECTOR" shall work.